# Django: Server Error (500) when trying to add an instance of a model

Tags: django, server, model

When I go on `localhost:8000/admin` and click on "Quotes   +ADD" it shows me error 500 instead of the editing interface. "Posts" works well. I just want to know if, without seeing the code, you could just tell me the different possible sources of this problem ?
[image]

EDIT: Here are `models.py` and `admin.py`:

**models.py**

```
class TimestampedModel(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# Create your models here.
class Post(TimestampedModel):

    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default='')

    intro = models.TextField(default='')
    title_one = models.TextField(default='')
    text_one = models.TextField(default='')
    title_two = models.TextField(default='')
    text_two = models.TextField(default='')
    title_three = models.TextField(default='')
    text_three = models.TextField(default='')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title

class Quote(models.Model):
    quote = models.TextField(default='')
    author = models.CharField(max_length = 60, default='')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.quote
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Quote

# Register your models here.
admin.site.register(Post)
admin.site.register(Quote)
```

I also would like to let you know that when I try to make migrations and then migrate, it says "No changes detected".

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/blog/quote/

relation "blog_quote" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_quote"
```

Comment: Provide us your models.py and admin.py

Comment: Hi gachdavit, I added these files.

Answer (score 1):

I'll guess it might be `OperationalError` due to not running migrations for `Quotes` model.

Providing `models.py` and `admin.py` contents would make it much easier to debug though.

Comment: Hi Krzysztof Borkowski, I added these two files.

Comment: ProgrammingError at /admin/blog/quote/

relation "blog_quote" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "blog_quote"

Comment: Looking at your models there should be `quote` table in the database but your error references `blog_quote` relation. Are you sure all migrations has been run?